# Отдельный background для span в переменной PHP

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

Добрый день, уважаемые.

Есть строка в коде - `<span><?=$arItem["TEXT"]?></span>`, от этой строки на странице приходят три разных значения, (например: текст один, текст два и текст три).
Как этим трем значениям установить разный фон?
Рад буду любой вашей помощи, или подскажите в какую сторону копать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS:

```
.red{background: #f00;}
.green{background: #0f0;}
.blue{background: #00f;}
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
$_tmp = array('red', 'green', 'blue');
$_tmp_length = count($_tmp) -1;
?>
```

Далее ваш участок:

```
<span class="<?=$_tmp[mt_rand(0, $_tmp_length)]?>"><?=$arItem["TEXT"]?></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Как минимум можно в лоб:

```
echo "<span style='background: #f00;'>" . $aritem["text1"] . "</span>";
echo "<span style='background: #0f0;'>" . $aritem["text2"] . "</span>";
echo "<span style='background: #00f;'>" . $aritem["text3"] . "</span>";
```